# KineticJS .on() not working on cloned shape

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I'm making an editable pattern that users can use and reuse to make a larger pattern. 
When users drag the first small pattern into the large pattern grid, I clone it, add it to another layer and let users reuse or edit it. 
The cloned node is still editable and draggable, but the bound events are not firing with interaction.
Here's my code:

```
 var B = A = new Kinetic.Shape();
 var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 1000,
    height: 650
  });
 var Alayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
 var Blayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

 var BGrid = new Kinetic.Group();

for(var v = 0; v < 4; v++){
for(var h = 0; h < 4; h++){
    (function(){
        var grid = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 300 + (h * 120),
            y: 50 + (v *120),
            width: 120,
            height: 120,
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            listening: false
        });
        BGrid.add(grid);
    })();  
 }

}

(function() {
  var AS = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 150,
    y: 110,
    width: 120,
    height: 120,
    draggable:true,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    offset: [60,60],
    });
B = AS;
Alayer.add(B);
})();

Blayer.add(BGrid);


stage.add(Blayer);
stage.add(Alayer);

Blayer.on('click', function(evt) {
 B = evt.targetNode;
 B.setStroke('red');

});
B.on('dragend',function(){
   var px = B.getX();
   var py = B.getY();
//some code that's not executing
});
A.on('dragend',function(){
var sx = A.getX();
var sy = A.getY();
if((300 < sx && sx < 780) && (50 < sy && sy < 530)){
    A.moveTo(Blayer);
    B = A;
    var C = A.clone();
    C.setPosition(150,110);
    Alayer.add(C);
    A = C;
}else{
    A.setPosition(150,110);
}
Alayer.draw();
Blayer.draw();
});
```

I'd really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo:

```
B.on('dragend',function(){
  var px = B.getX();
  var py = B.getY();   // not b.getY();
  alert("dragend!");
  //some code that's executing
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/JYqJp/

Comment: typo was put in when I shortened the code for SO, wasn't the problem. For some reason, .on() is not working more than once.

Comment: Your jsfiddle only works on the first dragstart and doesn't clone the shape. But I think I figured it out though. Currently editting my code, will post the end result shortly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with, not sure if it'll help anyone, but I hope it does.

```
stage.on('dragend',function(e){
var t = e.targetNode;
var n = t.getName();
var sx = t.getAbsolutePosition().x;

if(300 < sx && sx < 780 && n == 'A'){

    //previous code for A

}else if(300 < sx && sx < 780 && n != 'A'){

    //previous code for B

}else if(n == 'A'){

    t.setAbsolutePosition(150,110);

}else{

    t.remove();
}
stage.draw();
});`
```